# Are non-language related algorithms allowed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Professor Adam's Kids (determine the maximum-flow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493875/professor-adams-kids)

This one confuses me. It seems to have nothing to do with programming AND also appears to be a veiled 'do my homework'.

However, I'm not sure if it should be flagged, what it would be flagged as, or of it's an edge case that should be allowed.

I seek guidance from the more experienced modding community please.

Comment: Have you read the debate in the comments there?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi To be fair, I read the debate in the comments and I'm _still_ not sure one way or the other. I think this is a pretty fair, and good, question to bring to Meta.

Comment: @Kendra, fair enough. IMHO there is not much of an issue since software algorithm questions are explicitly on-topic, but I guess we can debate on whether or not that question actually is about a software algorithm (it is to me).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I did, and became more confused, which is why I ask.

Comment: It is exercise 26.1-6 from "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas Cormen.  Republishing it without consent from the author is unlikely to be okay.  But we don't enforce copyright here so little can be done about it.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, so it's both homework and a software issue. I just didn't do enough research before asking for help. Thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant True, we don't enforce copyright, but it is perhaps a case of plagiarism. If so, then a flag could be raised presenting the evidence.

Comment: Obviously the solution is to forge a DCMA takedown on behalf of Cormen.  Problem solved.

Comment: @Louis I don't think asking questions about exercises coming from books is bad, *provided that the source is clearly indicated*. Which in this case was not done. I'd say the question should be edited to include the source, and then it should be fine. Of course if the book's authors demand that we delete the question we have to do it, but if I were one of them I wouldn't, I'd actually be happy about it, because it could potentially lead someone to buy it. In other words: let's be nice to them (by crediting them), and they'll probably be nice to us (by letting us keep the question).

Comment: @FabioTurati "I don't think asking questions about exercises coming from books is bad". And I've never claimed so. I prefer to flag posts that most likely are plagiarism rather than edit them because a) a second pair of eyes can help: if I'm mistaken the edit would be incorrect (I've run into some pretty hairy cases where determining what was created first was difficult (blog authors backdating posts, for instance)), b) if the user has a history of having done this, maybe it is time for a suspension, c) a note from a moderator is more likely to prevent the behavior from happening again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Questions about algorithms [are explicitly on topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  It **doesn't** matter if it's homework or not.

It's also a decent question since it shows efforts and one *could* see where they've made a mistake.  If I had time, I could draw the graph they're describing on my whiteboard, and see where they were going with it.

**There's no reason to flag this question**, since there's nothing inherently wrong with it from a bystander's perspective.

Now, if someone wanted to make a claim about the copyright of the materials or whether or not the question can be reposted verbatim like that, we  leave that to the copyright holders themselves to suss out.  It's not our role to fight that battle, and we'd be pretty poor at it anyway.

Now, you *might* make an argument against [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32892617/1079354), which is a word-for-word copy of another source of information without any citations as to who said it (the link alone isn't sufficient, as that may expire).

Comment: Although on-topic, I typically comment on formula questions that it might be answered more speedily and verbosely on math.stackexchage.com :)

Comment: If it's whiteboard stuff esp. algorithms (complexity analysis etc.) I usually go to [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).